# Sencha Touch sessionstorage, save and retrieve

Tags: sencha-touch, session-storage

Hi i am trying to use javascript session storage on my app in sencha touch with model, after a long search on the internet i am not getting lucky at all, please help if you can, Thanks.
This is my code so far.
**My Controller** the onStorage function works, getStorage usession.load fails to load, thats were i'm stuck

```
Ext.define('SideMenu.controller.Menu', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
currView:'home',
requires: ['SideMenu.model.Mymdl'],
config: {
        refs: {
               btn_localstore:'#btn_localstore',
               btn_getlocalstore:'#btn_getlocalstore'                     
              } 
        control: {
                 btn_localstore:{
                 tap: 'onStorage' 
                 },
                 btn_getlocalstore:{
                 tap: 'getStorage' 
                 },                    
              },
        onStorage:function(){
                        //create model and store data
                         var myMod = Ext.create('SideMenu.model.Mymdl',{
                         brandName:'Nike Jordan',
                         brandCat:'Sneakers'        
                         });
                        myMod.save({
                          success:function(res){
                          console.log('saved to model : '+res.get('brandName'));
                              }
                            });              
               }, 
           getStorage:function(){
                var usession = Ext.ModelMgr.getModel('SideMenu.model.Mymdl');
                console.log('model is :'+usession);

                usession.load(0, {
                          scope: this,
                          success: function(model, opp) { 
                          console.log('passed '+model.get('brandCat'));
                              },
                failure: function(record, operation) {
                console.log('failed : '+operation);
               // Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
                //====================================================
               // alert('could not get session details');
                //====================================================  
                   }
                  });

     }
}
```

**My Model**

```
Ext.define('SideMenu.model.Mymdl', {
extend    : 'Ext.data.Model',
xtype    : 'Mymdl',
requires:['Ext.data.proxy.SessionStorage'],
id : 'Mymdl',
config: {
    fields: [ 
        'brandName',   
        'brandCat'    
    ]
     ,

     proxy : {
         type: 'localstorage',
         id  : 'mymdl'
     } 
}
});
```

**My app.js** i excluded the other stuff dts not needed in this case

```
models: ['Mymdl'],
views: ['Main', 'Home'],
controllers: ['Menu'],

launch:function()
{
   Ext.create('SideMenu.model.Mymdl'); 
}
```

Your answer would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call the model load method using the id of the model data you want to retrieve from local storage.

You can get the id from the model save callback function

```
var modelId;
myMod.save({success:function(res){
              modelId = res.getId();
              console.log('saved to model : '+res.get('brandName'));
           }
          });
```

Then use this id when you load the model:

```
SideMenu.model.Mymdl.load(modelId, function(record) {
    console.log('Brand: ' + record.get('brandName'));
}
```

You can set the id value directly when you save the model. This would save you from having to retrieve and save the auto-generated id on each save.

Comment: Jeff Martin , Dude you just saved my life man, thanks a lot, i struggled with this for two days...dse guys a Sencha could'nt even help me, unfortunately i cant upvote cs of my low reputation...bt thnks bru, u r a genius man

Comment: just one more thing, how can i set the id value when i save the model.

Comment: The model id property is created automatically. You can use model.set('id,[value]) to set the value.